# Please fix the standard sans-serif page title

Tags: bug, design, help-pages, font

Once again the site design has been disrupted by a standard change.

This is how Help pages used to look:
[image: Old style, weight 400]

They now have *really* bold titles:
[image: Current style, weight 700]

Because of the size of the heading, **this unbalances the page.** It seems to work better on sites using the standard sans-serif font, or Palatino for serif, but doesn't work with Georgia. I suspect that that's because Georgia is not an old-style font, but rather transitional.

The new weight is achieved with the CSS `font-weight: bold`. Please consider changing this to **semi-bold** with weight 600 `font-weight: 600` since the font stack should support that. If a particular font doesn't have a "semi-bold" weight, or the client software support that, then the fallback is to use the next available heavier weight (700 or bold).
[image: Mock-up using weight 600]

Better still would be to match the `font-weight: normal` serif font used for questions:
[image: Question title, normal-weight serif font]